# Emacs saying: <M-kp-7> is undefined when dictating quotes with Dragon naturally speaking 12

Tags: emacs, speech-recognition

I dictating my text via Dragon Naturally Speaking 12 into Emacs. Whenever I say (translation from German): 'open quotes', I expect something like `"` or `»` to appear on the screen, but I simply get a message `<M-kp-2> is undefined` . Same goes for 'close quotes', I get `<M-kp-7> is undefined`.

Does anybody know how to define those virtual keyboard strokes? `(global-set-key [M-kp-2] "»")` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(global-set-key [M-kp-2] (lambda () (interactive) (insert "»")))
```

The command passed to `global-set-key` needs to be a function, even if it's just to insert a string.

Comment: Thank you. Here -- Germany -- the weekend already started and I'm not able to test before monday.